# CSS position a small image over other images

Tags: javascript, css

I have a question regarding an issue that I have in CSS, or maybe not an issue, but I'm not sure. Is it possible to position a small image (with position absolute), like a warranty badge let's say, over other bigger images, but the badge I need to have on all other images the same fixed position, on their bottom left corner. The problem is that this badge needs to be placed on the bottom left of the object from the image every time, but this object from those images has different widths, one is thinner, other is larger so when I place the badge over the bottom left of the object from the other image, the badge is not on the bottom left of that object anymore, I don't know if I'm very clear about this. Please ask me if I need to clarify something.

Comment: You may play around with display:grid  https://jsfiddle.net/Lcbmneok/ and give any size to the bigger image

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I've already put the badge on the bottom left of the images, but the problem is that in each image, I have a different object, let's say in one image I have a laptop, in other image I have a desktop PC and I need the badge to be on the bottom left corner of the laptop and PC, not on the container of the image.

Comment: you need a container for both images, so it can be used as a reference , that is a grid element or positionned element. figure is fine for images, but a div is also good. update example with different ratio images https://jsfiddle.net/Lcbmneok/2/  **If you shared your code, you'd have efficient answers and no closing votes ;)**

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I know, but I thought that the question can refer to a general issue. The problem is that the badge is absolute positioned over the bigger, relative one. I can achieve somehow this functionality with position absolute ? To calculate somehow the position of the badge based on the width of the object from the relative image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this all with some css and the [`after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) pseudo selector. Here is an example of that.

```css
.thing {
  padding: .5em;
  margin: .5em 0;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.computer_watermark::after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27);
  background-position-x: 0px;
  background-position-y: -500px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.laptop_watermark::after {
  content: "";
  width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Img/unified/sprites.svg?v=fcc0ea44ba27);
  background-position-x: 0px;
  background-position-y: -500px;
  filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(180deg) contrast(0.8);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thing computer_watermark">
  <p>
    this is a computer
  </p>
</div>

<div class="thing laptop_watermark">
  <p>
    this is a laptop
  </p>
</div>

<div class="thing computer_watermark">
  <p>
    this is a computer
  </p>
</div>

<div class="thing laptop_watermark">
  <p>
    this is a laptop
  </p>
</div>


<div class="thing laptop_watermark">
  <p>
    this is a laptop
  </p>
</div>

<div class="thing computer_watermark">
  <p>
    this is a computer
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me,  the problem is that in each image, I have a different object, let's say in one image I have a laptop, in other image I have a desktop PC and I need the badge to be on the bottom left corner of the laptop and PC, not on the container of the image

Comment: Just create 2 classes, `.computer_watermark` and `.laptop_watermark` then add `after` for both of those and tag the computers with the `.computer_watermark` class and laptops with the `computer_watermark` class.

Comment: @Christian I've updated the answer with an example of two classes

Comment: I have several images, I've wrote  laptop and desktop for example porpose. I need the badge to be absolute positioned on the same position of the laptop, pc , phone etc. Somehow to calculate the width of the object from the relative image and to be placed on the bottom left corner of the object from the relative image. I hope that is clear now.

Comment: You are going to have to create multiple classes representing all the different watermarks. If you look at the css the watermark is absolute positioned to the bottom right, you will need to tweak those properties to get the desired position. Let the css engine do the calculations for you, that's what it's best at.